# Faster alternatives to stacking large multiindex df and then converting to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have some medium-large data-frames that are multi indexed (see example code below for example), I would like to convert them into a dictionary. My current method is fairly simple and just requires multiple `stack()` then `to_dict()`. This works fine on small data-frames however, as the level of indexes increase and the data-frame becomes bigger this method becomes much slower. Does anyone know a faster way to do this?

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['crop1', 'crop2', 'crop3','crop4', 'crop5', 'crop6','crop7', 'crop8', 'crop9','crop10'],
                                  ['crop1', 'crop2', 'crop3','crop4', 'crop5', 'crop6','crop7', 'crop8', 'crop9','crop10'],
                                  ['crop1', 'crop2', 'crop3','crop4', 'crop5', 'crop6','crop7', 'crop8', 'crop9','crop10'],
                                  ['crop1', 'crop2', 'crop3','crop4', 'crop5', 'crop6','crop7', 'crop8', 'crop9','crop10']])
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Zara', 'LV', 'Roots'],
                                   ['p1', 'p2', 'p3','p4', 'p5', 'p6'],
                                  list(range(17))])
df = pd.DataFrame('-', idx, cols)
df = df.stack([0,1,2]).to_dict()
```

Note - My final dict should have both the current index and current column headers as keys
ie
`('crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'LV', 'p1', 0):value`

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How large is your actual DataFrame?  How long does it take currently and how long do you think would be acceptable?  What's the reason you want a dict at the end instead of a DataFrame?

Comment: My actual df is over 4mil when stacked, and takes about 5sec (I would like to get it as fast as possible). Because I have multiple dfs to convert. The dict is used by pyomo (linear programming package), unfortunately it requires a dict.

Comment: How about just populating the dict in the first place, instead of using a DataFrame when you actually want a dict?  Feasible?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I don't think that is feasible because the df is constructed by merging multiple dfs that are read in from a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.stack(level=[0,1,2]).to_dict()
```

out：

```
{('crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'LV', 'p1', 0): '-',
 ('crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'LV', 'p1', 1): '-',
 ('crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'LV', 'p1', 2): '-',
 ('crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'LV', 'p1', 3): '-',
 ('crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'LV', 'p1', 4): '-',
 ('crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'LV', 'p1', 5): '-',
 ('crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'LV', 'p1', 6): '-',
 ('crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'crop1', 'LV', 'p1', 7): '-',
...
```